# avoiding deep hash queries in ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I tidy up code that sets and requests deep hash values in ruby?

For example, say I have a hash like this:

```
  hash = {
    user_settings: {
      notifications: {
        overdue_tasks: { enabled: true, duration: 30 },
        created_overdue_tasks: { enabled: true, duration: 30 } 
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I avoid writing brittle access code like this:

```
  hash[:user_settings][:notifications][:overdue_tasks][:duration] = 5
```

Also, is there a recursive `symbolize_keys` that will symbolize all keys and not just the top level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the help from the blog :- [Ruby Nested Hash - Deep Fetch - Returning a (Default) Value for a Key That Does Not Exist in a Nested Hash](http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2012/08/20/ruby-nested-hash-deep-fetch-returning-a-default-value-for-a-key-that-does-not-exist-in-a-nested-hash/)  :

```
class Hash
 def deep_fetch(key, default = nil)
   default = yield if block_given?
   (deep_find(key) or default) or raise KeyError.new("key not found: #{key}")
 end

 def deep_find(key)
    key?(key) ? self[key] : self.values.inject(nil) {|memo, v| memo ||= v.deep_find(key) if v.respond_to?(:deep_find) }
  end
end


hash = {
    user_settings: {
      notifications: {
        overdue_tasks: { enabled: true, duration: 30 },
        created_overdue_tasks: { enabled: true, duration: 30 } 
      }
    }
  }

p hash.deep_fetch(:duration)
# >> 30
```

Comment: This is smart. But the catch is there are two keys named "duration" in this deep hash. Correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know such way to reduce to code to fetch the desired key/value, but I have a suggestion to make your hash plain by naming.

How about

```
hash = {
  user_settings: {
    overdue_task_notification_enabled:  true,
    overdue_task_notification_duration: 30,
    created_overdue_tasks_enabled:      true,
    created_overdue_tasks_duration:     30 
  } 
}
```

Then fetch it like

```
hash[:user_settings][:created_overdue_tasks_duration]
```

I think this arrangement looks easier to understand for peers and users.

Comment: This flattens the nesting, but might not work. It depends on how the hash is generated in the first place. If it's by hand it's one thing. If it's the result of nested database queries it might be harder to control.